# SAS Enterprise Guide - Rounding Numbers before PROC COMPARE

Tags: sas, rounding, enterprise-guide

So I want to compare a summation field from 2 tables based on certain grouped variables. But because I don't care of any difference smaller than .000099, I rounded the field to the 4th decimal before using PROC COMPARE, but I'm still seeing differences smaller than .000099.

I don't want to use the METHOD arguement in PROC COMPARE.

Comment: You might want to explain why you don't want to use the `METHOD` argument in `PROC COMPARE`; since you mention that I assume you have a reason for it.  It's possible the answer uses `METHOD` but can work around any problem you have with it.

Comment: I sincerely apologize guys. I figured out the mistake I was making, I was summing up rounded numbers in my query rather than rounding summed numbers. How do I close this question?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `criterion` option rather than `method`:

```
proc compare data = x criterion = 0.0001;
```

Some discussion can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146742.htm#a002473384) under **The Equality Criterion**.

Edit: As Joe points out this implicitly sets `method = relative`, so to fit the question `method = absolute` would also be necessary. But unfortunately that falls short of Jayesh's request...

Comment: This is the right answer; but it should be noted that this does change the **method** used - to `METHOD=RELATIVE`.

Comment: I'd (erroneously) assumed that it was an absolute comparison; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I think if you then set `method=absolute` one or the other statement would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely can't stand to change `METHOD`, then you do have the option of `FUZZ`, which will allow you to hide differences less than the fuzz factor.  It doesn't make the differences go away - they still flag as different - but it hides the difference (any difference < `FUZZ` will be shown as zero or missing depending on the context).  You would then have to postprocess your dataset or report in order to eliminate those differences by hand.

If you're seeing differences like this after rounding, what you're likely seeing is issues caused by floating point precision.  Even with rounding, the *next* significant digit can be affected; you would need to round to something even less significant to be sure of 'true' .0001 being suppressed. [IE, rounding doesn't work perfectly because the rounded number still has to be stored as a numeric - and since you round to decimal values, not to binary, it doesn't guarantee a correctly storable number.]